# Address of "test" returns the coordinates of 7701 E Kellogg Dr #750, Wichita, KS 67207, USA

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I wanted to test the geocode api by passing an invalid address, "test" as below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=test&key=YourAPIKey

and I did get results for this address:
7701 E Kellogg Dr #750, Wichita, KS 67207, USA
and with the detailed information..

How is this happening? and how to make the geocode API to show details only for "valid addresses" ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no mystic here. The Geocoding API web service is smart enough to be able search by business name as well. When you specify address `test` it just suggests a business that contains word `test` in its name.

Have a look at place ID `ChIJKRXSsdrjuocRt_IxVk8z1xA` that you get in the response using the Places API details endpoint

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJKRXSsdrjuocRt_IxVk8z1xA&fields=formatted_address,name,place_id&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You will get the following response

```
{
  "html_attributions":[

   ],
   "result":{
       "formatted_address":"7701 E Kellogg Dr #750, Wichita, KS 67207, USA",
       "name":"Pearson VUE Testing Center",
       "place_id":"ChIJKRXSsdrjuocRt_IxVk8z1xA"
   },
   "status":"OK"
}
```

So, as you can see the result of geocoding request corresponds to the business with name `Pearson VUE Testing Center`.

I hope this answer explains your doubt.

Comment: Thanks.. but how would I restrict the geocoding API to return only for a valid address. I'm really interested in getting the lat/long of a valid address - not places of interest or business name.. Please help

Comment: There is no way to restrict Geocoding API to only street_address results. The search stack of the service uses both address and business names. Try to file a feature request in Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188871&template=788906).